# JSF - URL bar won't update after form submitting

Tags: jsf

Here is a code I use :

**request.jsf**

```
<h:form>
  <!-- form inputs ... --> 

  <h:commandButton id="btnStart" value="START" action="#{bean.handleForm}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="message" />
  </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

When I click `btnStart` button, the form is submited and correctly processed by my bean. Unfortunately, the browser url bar still displays `http://myhost.com/request.jsf` whereas the content displays the outcome returned by `#{bean.handleForm}`.

How can I update the url bar correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your form is submitting to the current URL and JSF just changes the resource of the response. If you'd like to change the URL to be the one of the new resource, then you need to tell the webbrowser to send a new request on that. You can do that by performing a redirect. In JSF 2 it's a matter of adding `faces-redirect=true` as query string to the outcome.

```
public String handleForm() {
    // ...

    return "nextpage?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

Alternatively, if it's really a non-idempotent request, then I'd stick to the same page and just conditionally display the results in the very same page, if necessary by an include. Your action method can then return `null` or `void`.

Comment: faces-redirect does the trick ! Thanks :) But is there a way to tell JSF to submit the form to the `next-page` URL ?

Comment: By a custom `ViewHandler` along with some custom configuration file, yes.